# How to know, Outlook add in is running in Browser or Outlook App, using jquery or javascript?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

How to know, Outlook add in is running in Browser or App, using jquery or javascript.
Is there any key to know whether it is running from browser or Outlook App

Answer (score 1):

@Sunny, you can determine this by using `Office.onReady`

Here's sample code for you:

```
Office.onReady(function(info) {
    if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
        // This means you are running in Outlook.
    }
    else if (info.host == null) {
        // This means you are running in a browser, outside of Outlook
    }
    else {
        // This means you are running in some Office client that is NOT Outlook.
    }
});
```

More info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.1/office.context.mailbox.diagnostics), which returns Outlook, OutlookIOS, or OutlookWebApp

Use [Office.context.platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.contextinformation?view=office-js#platform), which works  for office add-ins in general (not only Outlook), this returns [Office.PlatformType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.platformtype?view=office-js)

Comment: I upvoted this answer, which is the right answer, despite the downvotes.  The Outlook Add-ins Team misunderstood the question.